# How to copy listview sub item text to clipboard using contextmenu copy?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void lstDisplayHardware_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                ListViewItem item = lstDisplayHardware.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
                ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();
                m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Cut"));
                m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Copy"));
                m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Paste"));

                if (item != null)
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                    m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem(string.Format("Do something to row {0}", item.Position.ToString())));
                    Clipboard.SetData(item.SubItems[1].Text, lstDisplayHardware);
                }
                m.Show(lstDisplayHardware, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            }
        }
```

lstDisplayHardware is the ListView control.
When I right click, it doesn't copy the data to the clipboard.

What I want to do is when I click/select "Copy" it will copy the  sub-item text to the clipboard.

Right now, it doesn't copy the text to the clipboard at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the Clipboard.SetData is what you want.

Try using Clipboard.SetText(item.SubItems[1].Text);

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you need to handle a menu item click:

```
MenuItem miCopy = new MenuItem();
miCopy.Click += miCopy_Click;

void miCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //what you want to do  
}
 ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();
m.MenuItems.Add(miCopy);
```